# Calculus 1 Proof

Tags: calculus, derivatives

How do I prove the following statement?

Suppose that $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$ and differentiable on $(a,b)$ and 
$$\lim_{x\to a^+}f'(x)=L.$$ Show that the right hand derivative at $a$ (consider limit definition) exists and equals $L.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We write the mean theorem on the interval $[a,x]$ for $x\in(a,b)$:
$$f(x)-f(a)=(x-a)f'(\alpha_x)$$
where $\alpha_x\in (a,x)$. Now if $x$ tends to $a$ then $\alpha_x$ tends to $a$ and by hypothesis $f'(\alpha_x)$ tends to $L$ so
$$f'(a^+)=\lim_{x\to a^+}\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}=\lim_{x\to a^+}f'(\alpha_x)=L$$

Answer (score 1):

**HINT:** Use the Mean Value Theorem.